# CORS error when hosting React front and Express Back end on an IIS server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, iis

I'm having some issues setting app my NodeJS application on an IIS server.

For the front end, it's being ran on an `IIS Application Site` which points to the front end build folder.

This front end will be hosted on `http://exampleIP`. This IP is accessible to any device on the network.

Now for the back end, the IIS is configured with a reverse proxy that basically routes all the traffic going to `http://exampleIP:8080/api` to the express server being hosted on `http://localhost:8080`.

Now, locally (Running front and back end on `localhost`) works fine. Also, any device can reach with no problems the endpoints

- `http://exampleIP`
- `http://exampleIP:8080/api` (I can even access API endpoints that return valid data)

But the issue arises when any request from the `exampleIP` tries reaching the express server with the reverse proxy on the backend.

Not sure why, but I am getting a CORS error on all of these requests, here is an example of a `fetch` request in the front end.

```
useEffect(() => {

fetch('http://exampleIP:8080/api/vulnerabilities/getVulnerabilities')

        .then((res) => res.json())

        .then((data) => {

            console.log("sast data: " + DataTransfer)

            setData(data.message)

        })

    },[])
```

On the reverse proxy, I've tried the following

- Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value `http://exampleIP`
- Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value `http://exampleIP:8080`
- Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value `http://exampleIP:8080/api`
- Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value `exampleIP`
- Added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value `*`

What could be going on here? No idea why the CORS error is popping up on every request, is there any additional configuration necessary here?

Comment: Can you share express CORS code ?

Comment: Please share the CORS error and your `package.json` file